# What error mode to use when running an ADO transaction in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, transactions, vbscript, ado

I am running a database transaction using ADO and VBScript in a classic ASP page, that involves multiple calls to Execute method of connection object (i.e. **conn.Execute**) .
I have found that I need to set 'On Error Resume Next' at the top of my page, so that when  any of the transaction calls ( i.e. conn.Execute ) fails, then I can follow it with roll back code.
**Can I run an ADO transaction, even when the error mode is 'On Error GoTo 0' rather than 'On Error Resume Next' in my classic ASP page?** Sample code for rolling back transaction is as below.

```
'Rollback transaction if a previous conn.Execute fails
if err.Number <> 0 then
    if tranCount = 1 then
       conn.RollbackTran
       tranCount = 0
    end if
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!
I usually don't do database transactions from classic ASP so Im not sure  that conn.Errors will trap errors before the ASP-script. But you can at least try...

```
IF conn.Errors.Count > 0 THEN
    response.write "whoops"
END IF
```

Otherwise it might help you to know that On Error Resume Next is effective only in the current scope. (see code below)

```
<%
    response.write "start"
    BadFunction()
    response.write "middle"  '//<--- This will be printed

    dim b : b = 8 / 0  '//Division by zero

    response.write "end"    '//<-- This will NOT be printed!




    Function BadFunction()
        On Error Resume Next
        dim a : a = 9 / 0  '//Division by zero

        BadFunction = a
    End function


%>
```